# T(f)=$\int_0^12xf(x)dx$. Then prove that $\|T\| =1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $T:C[0,1]\to R$ be defined by $T(f)=\int_0^12xf(x) \, dx$. Then prove that $\|T\| =1$.
Here $C[0,1]$ is equipped with supremum norm.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?  Do you understand what's being asked?

Answer (score 3):

You may write
$$
                Tf = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)d\mu(x), \;\;\; \mu(S)=\int_{S}2xdx.
$$
Therefore,
$$
               \|T\| = \|\mu\|= \int_{0}^{1}2xdx=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$||T(f)||=||\int_0^12xf(x)dx||\le \int_0^1||2xf(x)||dx \le2.||f||.\int_0^1xdx $

$\frac{||T(f)||}{||f||}\le 2.\int_0^1xdx$

${\sup_f{\in C[0,1]}}{\frac{||T(f)||}{||f||}}\le1$

$||T||\le 1$

The other inequality can be shown easily.

Comment: Hint: to prove the equality you can use a particular $f(x)$, in general it is helpful use a function such that the norm is equal to 1. Then $f(x)=1$, $||f(x)||=1$.

Comment: @Cuoredicervo that's not really a hint so much as a completion of this answer

Comment: My idea what to give a method to find in the general situation